# how can i respond a 426 Upgrade Required http status code with apache2.2/php?

Tags: apache, http, apache2, http-status-code-404

I want to return the status code 426 Upgrade Required using apache2 and/or php.

How can I do this?

I only found mod_rewrite which can set redirects with http status codes.

Answer (score 0):

mod rewrite does the job...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain.com
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule .* - [R=426,L]
</VirtualHost>
```